# Latest Twitter api and 280 character limit

Tags: ios, twitter, twtrcomposer

Twitter has recently changed the character count limit to 280 in all languages except a few ones.

In our iOS app, i have upgraded the pod file to use the latest Twitter api. For composing Tweets we use the Twitter's built-in UI using TWTRComposer. The issue is that the character limit is still 140 not 280. I was wondering if anybody know how to get the iOS app work with the 280 characters limit.

I have seen some apps like Twitterrific allows 280 characters. (see the image below)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:

According to twitter dev community, the Twitter Kit has not been yet updated to support the 280 characters tweets. So you may want to wait for future release or use your own view/UI to support 280 long tweets.